# SQL Query put a word in a field instead of 0?

Tags: sql, database

When i run *sql query* such as;

```
Select 
    F1 as name, 
    F2 as phone 
from Table where condition = true
```

If `F2 = 0`
i need to that field to be `No Phone Number` instead of `null` or `0`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that with a CASE statement:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN F2 = '0' THEN '(No Phone Number)' ELSE F2 END AS Phone
...
```

Comment: Your "AS Phone END" should be "END AS Phone"

Comment: This will come back with null if F2 is null.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN F2 = '0' OR F2 IS NULL THEN '(No Phone Number)' ELSE F2 END AS Phone
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `CASE` as;

```
SELECT 
    F1 As name, 
    CASE WHEN F2 IS NULL OR F2 = '0' THEN 'No Phone Number' ELSE F2 END As phone
FROM Table
WHERE condition = 'true'
```